# New to python and would like to understand argv syntax

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, compiler-errors, command-line-arguments, argv

This is my code :

```
    import sys 
    inp = open(sys.argv[1],'r')
    F=[]
    A=[]
        for i in inp:
        ar = i.split()
        F.append(float(ar[0]))
        A.append(complex(str(ar[1]).replace('i','j')))
```

... the code is bit long and continues to plot a graph

**Ques 1: inp = open(sys.argv[1],'r') # this syntax means you need to list the file name after the py file call in the terminal. However, I can't really understand how this is to be done ?**

*When I write - len(sys.argv) in console , my output is 1 
This means that it only has the script name*

**Ques2: How do I pass my data (text file)`enter code here` as an argument ?** The data file is a two column with second column as complex number.

**If I simply run the code, I get the following error: 
IndexError: list index out of range**

for example, the data is something like this :

```
2.908   2+0.6i
1.05   1.9818-0.073097i
1.0321  5.98225-0.075645i
1.0503  1.98193-0.07609i
```

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:
you would call your program as follows

```
python3 my_script.py data.txt
```

data.txt is now added to `sys.argv`

In order to get the command line arguments in the console and run the script, you need to call python with the `-i` flag, i.e.
    python3 -i my_script.py data.txt

Question 2:
add the text to a text file, e.g. `data.txt` and then call the script just like in question 1.